# What's the mathematical definition of quaternion 3x3 covariance matrices, and how does it relate to euler angles?

Tags: kalman-filter

I'm adapting a KF orientation filter that represents the orientation as quaternion, and uses a 3x3 covariance matrix. Would someone know what 3x3 covariance represents in the case of a quaternion, and how that representation would relate to euler angles ?

Comment: Could you post or link to the code?  If I remember correctly, one of the quaternions is a normalizer.   You might be looking at something like what they discuss in this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11667783/quaternion-and-normalization) (see the answer by vpozdyayev):

Comment: How are you using a 3x3 covariance matrix with a quaternion? Why not just use the [Madgwick filter](http://x-io.co.uk/open-source-imu-and-ahrs-algorithms/)? Accuracy meets/exceeds the Kalman filter, output is in quaternion format. Already developed, and free source code in C/C#/Matlab format.

Comment: I'm using an already-developed filter, just trying to understand its error representation https://github.com/rock-slam/slam-quater_ikf